# Getting Nova Server From Metadata

Tags: java, openstack-nova, jclouds, openstack-api

Getting Nova Server From Metadata

Hi,

I'm using jclouds SDK with Java to retrieve OpenStack Nova Servers, i can retrieve the server through its **id**, but i didn't find any other way that i can get a Nova Server.

I saw in the OpenStack documentation that i can get a server using the API  **/servers/{server_id}** or i can list all the servers, but assume that i have a case that i only need to get the servers that designated with certain data, such as i need to list all servers that are designated as **delete-able**  which i can set in the metadata when i create the server 
in this case, is there any way to use some sort of filtration  to the metadata for the servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can filter directly by the server metadata, but you should be able to filter using any of the [query parameters that are available when listing servers](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#list-servers).

You can just call the `ServerApi.list(options)` by passing the query parameters you want. You can build the options object by using `PaginationOptions.queryParameters` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i saw in this [link](https://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/compute/server_concepts.html#server-query) ,in querying servers the sentence was **For administrator, most of the server attributes can be used as query options** can that be any help to my case?

Comment: in the AWS i can get instances by their tags (the equivalent to metadata in OpenStack) without the instance id, according to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#examples) its more like a filtration way to get EC2 instances, is there anyway i can do the same at OpenStack to get Nova instances?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can filter by the query parameters the Nova API offers. The link I passed details them all. If there is a query parameter in the Nova RET API that allows you to filter by what you want, then yes, you can use it.

Comment: Hi, in the URL that you have shared, it says there is filtering according to tags (the one which should match all tags), as for the solution that you have shared `PaginationOptions.queryParameters` how to set in the options that the filtration should be according to is tags? can that be done from the Options? thanks